# How can I get instance of custom view in order to retrieve in a loop?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to show rows according to my data. For example I will create 10 rows dynamically in a loop and this row is a custom view actually. So I need to do it in main activity. Can you show me how to do?

example.xml

```
<TableLayout 
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="titletitletitletitletitletitle"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="DescriptionDescriptionDescription" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>   
</TableLayout>`
```

CustomView.java

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout
{
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);       
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.example,this);
    }

    private void init(Context context){

    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
    </ScrollView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list adapter and a wrapper and inflate the custom view each time. Actually on the seocnd round for your code to be more eficient you should "reuse" the inflated view so that you don't inflate each time. Check for example this tutorial:
http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/04/custom-widget-adapters.html